# java.net sockets, readline and line terminators (VNC connection)

Tags: java, sockets, readline, vnc, terminator

I am using x11vnc and I want to develop simple client for it.
So, the work is:

1. recieve info from socket
2. send info
3. recieve next data
4. send another info

and etc.

So, for example, I am using the next simple code:

`LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String test = null;`

```
    try {
        test = lnr.readLine();
        System.out.println(test);
        test = lnr.readLine();
        System.out.println(test);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.exit(0);
```

The first message from server I got without errors (first readLine). The next message is empty (or without any line terminator for readLine) and I have infinite loop.
lnr.ready() not works for me.

So, how can I read from socket when data from socket sometimes have no "\n", "\r", "\r\n" or if the socket buffer is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only RFB/VNC message that is terminated by a newline is the initial version exchange. In fact the RFB/VNC protocol is somewhat deficient in that it does not have any unique message framing; you have to process every message or you will lose your place. You probably will need to read directly from the socket or from the InputStreamReader. Wrapping it with LineNumberReader won't work.

The best reference I have found on the RFB/VNC protocol: http://tigervnc.org/cgi-bin/rfbproto

Comment: Yep, thanks, so how can I read from InputStreamReader? What methods I mean? And when can I use LineNumberReader? I am new to Java and I cannot understand when to use such «identical» classes (not ISR and LNR but BufferReader and such one).

Comment: > Yep, thanks, so how can I read from InputStreamReader? *And also direct from socket?

Comment: @purple, the read() method. See the [InputStreamReader reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html). Also see [LineNumberReader reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html)